# Expresso store add if statement to order confirmation email

Tags: expresso-store, email, html-email, confirmation

Is it possible to put an if statement in the order confirmation email?

like so?

```
{if shipping_address2}{shipping_address2}<br />{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be able to use most EE tags without issues in the Store email templates.

Comment: When I put that code in the order confirmation email template I do not get the order confirmation email.  I can only assume that it causes an error somewhere but since I don't really have a way to debug it (not that I know of) I can't be 100% what the issue is.

Comment: Apparently it does work, the order confirmation emails where being caught by the spam filter.

Comment: I usually create my emails as EE templates first wrapped in a `{exp:store:orders}` loop to get the formatting and everything setup properly then copy that into an email template.

Comment: I was not aware that is how it worked, now that I do that is a great idea.